# Network stopped working

Tags: networking, internet

Hey guys over the last few days my network has stopped working on my laptop. I have it set to a static IP address which has worked fine over the last few weeks. Nm-applet and wicd both show that I am connected but nothing will load. I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 and it seems to be fine.

Ubuntu 18.04.1
kernel is 4.4.0-134-generic

I tried wicd to see if Nm-applet was missing something. I'm not running them together. I will save the other 2 outputs and upload shortly. However I just looked at my /etc/resolv.conf and it's saying my name server is 127.0.0.53 which I did not set. Could that be why? I can't ping Google.com as it says name or service not known.

`sudo lshw -c network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 46:6b:3c:cd:a1:f6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-134-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:d0500000-d050ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: f0:de:f1:e1:2f:53
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:24 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
```

`ifconfig`

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f0:de:f1:e1:2f:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 247167  bytes 22047389 (22.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 247167  bytes 22047389 (22.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 46:6b:3c:cd:a1:f6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 552971  bytes 226093241 (226.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 71666  bytes 8239062 (8.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: What version Ubuntu? What version kernel? Why running wicd vs NetworkManager? What does `ifconfig` show? What does `sudo lshw -c network` show? Can you `host google.com`? Edit these answers into your question, not in the comments please. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: You have a DNS problem. That's the wrong kernel for Ubuntu 18.04.1. How did it get there? Do `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and do you see dnsmasq? Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping 8.8.8.8, but can't ping google.com. It seems to be problem with your nameservers.

You can check it here: /etc/resolv.conf This filecontains the list of nameservers use your system.

If it is your problem, you could create/edit this this file: /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail. And add there some public nameservers. For example:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

This file allows you add this public nameservers to the end of the /etc/resolv.conf.

File /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head does the same, but adds nameservers to the top of the /etc/resolv.conf.

After editing tail or head file, you should reboot your system in order to implement this changes.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AHQmKYyJ  https://pastebin.com/E4fkzRx8 @heynnema here is the output of the commands you asked for.

Comment: You indicate the head and tail edits both add nameservers to the END of /etc/resolv.conf. Accurate? Also, rather than editing these files, why not have the user use the GUI settings already present in each connection profile?

Comment: @heynnema My bad! Thanks for letting me know! I edited my message.

Comment: As I mention, you could also talk about using the GUI to do the same thing. As you can see from my answer, it's probably a dnsmasq/systemd-resolved problem... and an incorrect kernel.

Comment: systemd-resolved gets list of resolvers sources from `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. And `/etc/resolve.conf` one of this sources. And as TS mentioned: `I just looked at my /etc/resolv.conf and it's saying my name server is 127.0.0.53`. So I guess that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the **wrong kernel** for 18.04.1. 4.15.0-36 would be closer to correct.

You have a **dns problem**. That's why you can't `ping google.com`.

**Regarding `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`...**

Do a `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv` and look for `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`, and if both are running, you need to disable the DNS part of `systemd-resolved` by editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and...

change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

postnote: Do **NOT** manually edit `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I actually have 4.15.0-33 as well. I had booted into that one to see if maybe an update had broken something. Neither of the grep commands display any output.

Comment: @RobFitz Please [edit] additional information into your question rather than spreading it out in comments. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @RobFitz one of the ps/grep commands should have returned **something**. Please copy/paste those commands out of my answer and try them again. Also, take a screenshot of the panel where you setup the static address, and edit that into your question, as the problem could be there also. Report back to "@heynnema".

Comment: I was able to get online by adding the google nameservers to the tail file. Thank you